# Swift relativePath property that FileManager.default.enumerator outputs is full path

Tags: ios, swift, url, relative-path, nsfilemanager

I want to get relative paths, but I get full paths in the following code.
Xcode 14.3

```
let  homePath = NSHomeDirectory()
let  homeURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: ".", relativeTo: URL(fileURLWithPath: homePath))
guard let  fileEnumeratorIncludingSubFolder = FileManager.default.enumerator(
        at: homeURL,
        includingPropertiesForKeys: [],
        options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants])
else { fatalError() }

for case let fileURL as URL in fileEnumeratorIncludingSubFolder {
    print(fileURL.relativePath)  // Expected relative path but full path
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780432-relativepath "this is the same as `path` if `basePath` is `nil`" - is `basePath` `nil`?

Comment: Add `.producesRelativePathURLs` to the enumeration options and you will get what you want.

Comment: 'homeDirectoryForCurrentUser' is unavailable in iOS

Comment: Is this question unuseful (-1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing out the `baseURL`s of the URLs you are getting:

```
print(fileURL.baseURL)
```

You should see that these are all nil. Because of this, [`relativePath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780432-relativepath) returns just returns the `path` component:

> This is the same as `path` if `baseURL` is nil.

It turns out that giving out absolute URLs is just how `enumerator(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:)` behaves by default.

Fortunately, there is an additional option that you can pass, so that it [`producesRelativePathURLs`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/directoryenumerationoptions/3088818-producesrelativepathurls).

```
guard let fileEnumeratorIncludingSubFolder = FileManager.default.enumerator(
        at: homeURL,
        includingPropertiesForKeys: [],
        options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants, .producesRelativePathURLs]) // here!
else { fatalError() }
```